# Odata v3 Web Api navigation with composite key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, composite-key

I have a Web Api using Odata v3, with some entities a composite key, like this one:

```
public class AerodromoAdministracaoData
{
    [Key]
    [Column("idAerodromo", Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short IdAerodromo { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("data", Order = 1, TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }       

    public virtual Aerodromo Aerodromo { get; set; }
}
```

I followed [this msdn article and created a NavigationRoutingConvention](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Support-Composite-Key-in-d1d53161#content). The application handles composite keys fine now. However, navigation Links like this one don't work:

```
http://localhost/WebApiV3/AerodromoAdministracaoData%28idAerodromo=1,data=%272014-10-24%27%29/Aerodromo
```

I keep getting a "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request" as if the method was not implemented in the controller. By the way, this is the controller method:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public Aerodromo GetAerodromo([FromODataUri] short idAerodromo, [FromODataUri] DateTime data)
    {
        AerodromoAdministracaoData result = Store.AerodromoAdministracaoData.Find(idAerodromo, data);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return result.Aerodromo;
    }
```

I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766354/asp-net-web-api-odata-navigation-links-when-using-composite-keys) talking about exactly the same problem, but I haven't figured out how [Nikon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565070/nikon-the-third?tab=summary) handled the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Eduardo

From MSDN article [Support Composite Key in ASP.NET Web API OData](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Support-Composite-Key-in-d1d53161#content)

```
public class CompositeKeyRoutingConvention : EntityRoutingConvention
{
   ....
}
```

The above routing convention can cover the following Uri templates:

- ~/entityset/key
- ~/entityset/key/cast

But, it can't cover **~/entityset/key/navigation**

**The fix is simple**, just derived from `NavigationRouteConvention` as below

```
public class CompositeKeyRoutingConvention : NavigationRoutingConvention
{
    ...
}
```

Below is the debug information:
[image: The debug information:]

Please make sure: if you want support both Uris:

- /AerodromoAdministracaoData%28idAerodromo=1,data=%272014-10-24%27%29
- /AerodromoAdministracaoData%28idAerodromo=1,data=%272014-10-24%27%29/Aerodromo

You must have two custom routing conventions, one derived from `EntityRoutingConvention`, the other one derived from `NavigationRoutingConvention`.

Hope it can help. Thanks.